# Altering a Class to create a list

Tags: java

I need to update my Country class so that it can store a list of languages, I also need a field for the list, a getter, and a method that allows me to add a language to the collection. I very green when it comes to programing. This is what I have so far.

```
public class Country {
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private long population;
        private double medianAge;
        private List<String> languages;

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();


        /**
         * Create a Country object with the given properties
         */
        public Country(int id, String name, long population, double medianAge) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.population = population;
            this.medianAge = medianAge;

        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public long getPopulation() {
            return population;
        }

        public double getMedianAge() {
            return medianAge;
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how do I update my Country class so that it can store a list of languages, I also need a field for the list, a getter, and a method that allows me to add a language to the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the member `list` - cannot see a reason for you to have it.

You constructor can be:

```
public Country(int id, String name, long population, double medianAge) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.population = population;
        this.medianAge = medianAge;
        this.languages = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

Then you can have a method to add a language to the list:

```
public void addLanguage (String language) {
    languages.add(language);
}
```

Finally a method to return the list of languages as given below:

```
public List<String> getLanguages() {
    return languages;
}
```

[More information](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) on how `ArrayList` works

Comment: I agree, the member 'list', which was defined using List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); is useless. You should probably remove it.

Comment: Would this also work if it's a collection? Cause a country can have more than one language.

Comment: List is a collection. Check the link I have mentioned, as well as the documentation of [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need a getter method to access languages like below

```
getLanguages(){
    return this.languages;
}
```

And a method which ads one language to existing list.

```
addLanguageToList(String language){
    this.getLanguages().add(language);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to add an initializer for languages? You can use the list.add() method.

```
public class Country{
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private long population;
  private double medianAge;
  private ArrayList<String> languages = new ArrayList<String>();

  public Country(int id, String name, long population, double medianAge String language) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.population = population;
        this.medianAge = medianAge;
        this.languages.add(laguage);

   }

   public int getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public long getPopulation() {
       return population;
   }

   public double getMedianAge() {
       return medianAge;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, Create a getter and two add method, one for adding one language and another add method for adding list of language to existing language list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Country {
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private long population;
        private double medianAge;
        private List<String> languages;

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();


        /**
         * Create a Country object with the given properties
         */
        public Country(int id, String name, long population, double medianAge) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.population = population;
            this.medianAge = medianAge;

        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public long getPopulation() {
            return population;
        }

        public double getMedianAge() {
            return medianAge;
        }

        public List<String> getLanguages() {
            return languages;
        }

        public void addLanguage(String language) {
            this.languages.add(language);
        }
        public void addLanguages(List<String> languages) {
            this.languages.addAll(languages);
        }
}
```